# Why doesn't 'discrete delay bloc' work with all discrete signals?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I try to make this equation in simulink:

```
ARRIVba(Ka) =((Ca - toba(Ka)).* ENTERba(Ka)/ Ca)+ (toba(Ka -1).* ENTERba(Ka -1)/ Ca);
```

By using a Matlab function bolck.

So I use a dicrete delay bloc to make

```
toba(Ka -1) and ENTERba(Ka -1).
```

But I don't have the same signal delayed, just for

```
toba(Ka -1), for ENTERba(Ka -1)
```

I have the same signal.

Can you help me please?

[Function Bloc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IiLh.jpg)

[toba signal before and after the delay block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDHMp.jpg)

Comment: The delay block does work for all signals.  Something else is going on, and without seeing your exact code and (part) of the model nobody here is going to be able to help.

Comment: Thank you Phil for your response. I add the pictures to discribe more my problem. I hope they will be useful

Comment: You need to at least have the same y-axis scale on the plots.  And without knowing the sample time it's hard to interpret the x-axis.

Comment: You're right Phil. I use Time scope in place of scope, and it gives me the same signal delayed by 1s. Thank you for your help :)